Nonce not getting reset when transactions are dropped
I am using the transaction manager from the Nethereum package to send transactions automatically. However, I am encountering an issue where multiple transactions are getting stuck, specifically up to nonce 100.
The problem is that the nonce is not resetting even after 3 days. However, when I use another wallet like Metamask, it detects the correct nonce.
Why is the nonce not resetting in the Nethereum transaction manager, and how can I resolve this issue?
I am expecting the nonce to get reset to the nonce for which the transaction is to be updated
